# What is the role of IceConnectionState and IceGatheringState in webrtc

Tags: webrtc

How to make use of IceConnectionState and IceGatheringState while sending the icecandiates to the peer in webrtc ?

Answer (score 3):

- ice gathering is the generation of the local candidates you will send to the remote peer either in the offer sdp (full ICE) or separately (trickle ICE).
- ice gathering state is the state of the connection with the remote peer based on your trying of the remote candidates received through your chosen signaling method.

The ice gathering state is not so important, as the application logic does not care usually about those (the application might monitor the candidates and know if the gathering is done when a null candidate surfaces), the ice connection states are VERY important to know if a connection was established and your application should focus on that. The peer connection state can be stable, and all the handshake done, without media flowing if the ICE connection state is failed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my application I see the iceConnectionState as completed and iceGatheringState as complete but still it doesn't display the video.

Comment: then, you need to follow the data:
1. check on the wire on sender side that the media packets are indeed flowing (using wireshark/tcpdump, ...)
2. check on the wire on the receiver side that media packets are received.
3. check that you are connecting the media to a renderer. Ice completed means you are receiving packets, but it s up to the application to do something (like rendering the video, or playing the audio) with it.